# Using display none instead of condition state rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I m trying to use conditional rendering (in this specific case) that would allow me to make something like :

```
<Image
    source={{ uri: "https://images4.alphacoders.com/221/221716.jpg" }}
    style={this.state.isLoaded ? styles.loaded : { display: "none" }}
    onLoadEnd={() => {
    console.log("test"), this.setState({ isLoaded: true });
    }}
/>
```

The main problem is that React Native doesn't seem to be able to use its internal lifecycle functions when the `display: none` style is used, and thus doesn't call `onLoadEnd`. It doesn't log anything.

I don't have any idea how to encounter this problem while using `display` style props

Comment: Got some weird behaviors when using display "none" too :
When back to "flex" value my component is not properly rendered. Your question about lifecycle seems legit to me.

Answer (score 25):

#### TL;TR

**`{ transform: [{ scale: 0 }] }`**
is a good solution

#### IMHO

Your question about lifecyle / rendering seems legit.

Since I can't give any answer actually...

I got some weird bug recently trying to use `{ display: 'none' }` (when restoring display to `'flex'` some children component still didn't render).
Or `{ width: 0, height: 0 }` (when back to `'flex'` the layout was not restored).

Needless to say that avoiding rendering via some was usual tricks ( `return enabled && <MyComponent {...}/>`) was not the solution (mounting & unmounting components requires heavy computations that are breaking animations framerate).

As I was looking to hide components during animations without break the framerate, I've found that `{ transform: [{ scale: 0 }] }` was the best solution:

- layout is not altered (`alignSelf: 'center'` still works)
- the hidden component won't catch any touch events and allow underlying components to react to touches

My implementation is something like:

```
view.setNativeProps({ transform: [{ scale: 0 }]
```

Answer (score 14):

Next time, it would be super cool if you setup a snack to demo your issue.

This pattern will work for you...

```
<Image
  source={{ uri: "https://images4.alphacoders.com/221/221716.jpg" }}
  style={[{width: 0, height: 0,},
  this.state.isLoaded && {width: 400, height: 400,}]}
  resizeMode="contain"
  onLoadEnd={() => {
    this.setState({ isLoaded: true });
  }}
/>
```

I've created a [demo on snack for you](https://snack.expo.io/H1rZe8ygG)

## update with `display: none`

```
<Image
  source={{ uri: "https://images4.alphacoders.com/221/221716.jpg" }}
  style={[{width: 400, height: 400,},
  !this.state.isLoaded && {display: 'none'}]}
  resizeMode="contain"
  onLoadEnd={() => {
    this.setState({ isLoaded: true });
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you for that. My underlying question was : is the display: none function really stops lifecycle ?

Comment: I'm not sure how it matters whether `display: none` interferes with the lifecycle or not. I provided a solution to the problem. In anycase, if it's important to use `display: none` I've provided another working solution to show that. I'd love to know why `display: none` is important to you though.

Comment: FYI, here's the problem I want to catch : https://github.com/mfrachet/rn-placeholder/issues/30

Comment: Ah, that makes so much more sense then! So, it then the answer is `display: none` seems to work with the `onLoadEnd` lifecycle method. Does that help you resolve your issue? The `rn-placeholder` component looks pretty cool too.

Comment: Maybe it's device specific because it seems to be working fine on my phone...

I see two images on my MotoZ and here's the log...

XT1650: I never pass there
XT1650: I pass there

Comment: Well, I'll investiguate from an ios perspective so. I m running it on iphone SE

Comment: You can use display none and display flex in react native

Answer (score 4):

I've tried various things, but finally `style: {height: 0, width: 0, opacity: 0}` worked for me.